# How do I solve Wicket Error: Unable to find resource

Tags: java, weblogic, wicket

I am new to wicket. I am trying to run someone else's code in my local machine which is working in production. I have java code and html code in same folder. I have wicket id "instructions" defined for corresponding java id but still I'm getting resouce not found error.

```
ERROR - XYZApplication  - Unable to find resource: instructions for component: instructions [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label]
```

//java file

```
        ResourceModel instructionsModel = new ResourceModel("instructions"); 
        instructions = new Label("instructions", instructionsModel);
        add(instructions);
```

html file

```
<div wicket:id="instructions" class="instructions"></div>
```

Can you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Your confusion comes from the fact that you use the name `instructions` for several different things. This makes it hard for you to understand which one is missing. For debugging purposes you can temporarily rename some of the variables to see which one is the problematic one.

Comment: Thanks @martin-g for your comment. I changed my code to: 
MyPanel.java
`ResourceModel instructionsModel = new ResourceModel("guide"); 
instructionsLabel = new Label("guide", instructionsModel);
add(instructionsLabel);
`
MyPanel.html
`<div wicket:id="guide" class="instructions"></div>
`
MyPanel.properties
`guide=testing`
I am still getting the same error. Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Error I am getting now:
`ERROR - XYZApplication             - Unable to find resource: guide for component: guide [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label]
java.util.MissingResourceException: Unable to find resource: guide for component: guide [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label]
        at org.apache.wicket.Localizer.getString(Localizer.java:266)
        at org.apache.wicket.Localizer.getString(Localizer.java:135)`

Answer (score 3):

A `ResourceModel` is used for internationalization, so it's looking for an entry in one of your resource bundles with the name `instructions`, but can't find it.

Resource bundles follow the same naming conventions as your HTML and Java files, so if you have `MyPanel.java` and `MyPanel.html`, the resource bundle could be named `MyPanel.properties` (there are more options though).

A resource file generally looks like this:

```
my.label=Hi, I'm a label
my.description=This is a description
```

In your case, an entry like this should be present:

```
instructions=To use this form, you need to enter data
```

It could also be the case that a bundle is defined at the application level, so if you have `MyApplication.java`, your resource bundle will be in the same package and called `MyApplication.properties`.

You can read more about [how internationalization works in wicket](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_internationalization_with_wicket) on the Wiki.

If these files are already present **and** contain the correct entry, then what might be the case is that your `.properties` files aren't being bundled into the application on your local machine. In that case you need to check both your build tool settings (Maven's `pom.xml` or Gradle's `build.gradle`, for instance) as well as your IDE's settings.

Comment: I do have MyPanel.properties file in the same package as MyPanel.java and MyPanel.html. MyPanel.properties looks `instructions=test`. I am using Ant build.xml file to create MyApplication.jar and deploy it in weblogic local server. Can you please elaborate more on how to bundle .properties file into the application on my local machine both on build.xml and IDE. Again, I am new to ant and weblogic.

Comment: Most probably Ant is not copying the.properties file in the classpath. Check whether it is next to the .class file after build.

Comment: I copied all .properties files to classes dir. I can see .class file and its corresponding .properties files next to each other. But still I am getting same error.
`<copy todir="${classes.dir}" verbose="true">
   <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/java/main">
    <exclude name="**/*.java" />
    <exclude name="**/Log4j.xml" />
    <exclude name="**/log4j.xml" />
    <include name="**/*.properties" />
   </fileset>
   <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/wsdls">
    <include name="**/*.wsdl" />
   </fileset>
   <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/resources">

   </fileset>
  </copy>`